# Using function arguments within the constant expression of a non-type template paramater

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, compiler-bug

In what context can a function argument be part of the constant expression provided to a non-type template parameter? Is the expected behavior affected by use of an unevaluated operand in any sort of way? What does the C++20 standard say about the validity of these examples?

```
struct t { static constexpr auto b = true; };
template<auto> inline constexpr auto v = true;

// clang ok, gcc nope, msvc ok
constexpr auto f(t x) -> decltype(v<x.b>)
{ return true; }
static_assert(f({}));

// clang ok, gcc ok, msvc nope
constexpr auto g(t x) -> decltype([]<auto = x.b>{}(), true)
{ return true; }
static_assert(g({}));

// clang nope, gcc ok, msvc nope
constexpr auto h(auto x) -> decltype([]<bool = x.b>{}(), true)
{ return true; }
static_assert(h(t{}));
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/cb4KfePPx)

---

The error message from GCC with function `f`:

```
<source>:5:36: error: missing template arguments before '<' token
    5 | constexpr auto f(t x) -> decltype(v<x.b>)
      |                                    ^
<source>:5:41: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
    5 | constexpr auto f(t x) -> decltype(v<x.b>)
      |                                         ^
<source>:7:15: error: 'f' was not declared in this scope
    7 | static_assert(f({}));
      |               ^
```

The error message from MSVC with function `g`:

```
<source>(10): error C2065: 'x': undeclared identifier
<source>(10): error C3889: call to object of class type '<lambda_1>': no matching
    call operator found
<source>(10): note: could be 'auto <lambda_1>::operator ()(void) const'
<source>(10): note: 'auto <lambda_1>::operator ()(void) const': could not deduce
    template argument for '_T1'
<source>(10): note: left of '.b' must have class/struct/union
<source>(10): note: type is 'unknown-type'
<source>(10): error C3615: constexpr function 'g' cannot result in a constant
    expression
<source>(10): note: failure was because type 'unknown-type' is not a literal type
<source>(12): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
<source>(12): note: a non-constant (sub-)expression was encountered
```

The error message from Clang with function `h`:

```
<source>:15:48: error: variable 'x' cannot be implicitly captured in a lambda
  with no capture-default specified
   15 | constexpr auto h(auto x) -> decltype([]<bool = x.b>{}(), true)
      |                                                ^
<source>:15:38: note: while substituting into a lambda expression here
   15 | constexpr auto h(auto x) -> decltype([]<bool = x.b>{}(), true)
      |                                      ^
<source>:17:15: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into
  function template 'h' [with x:auto = t]
   17 | static_assert(h(t{}));
      |               ^
<source>:15:23: note: 'x' declared here
   15 | constexpr auto h(auto x) -> decltype([]<bool = x.b>{}(), true)
      |                       ^
<source>:15:38: note: lambda expression begins here
   15 | constexpr auto h(auto x) -> decltype([]<bool = x.b>{}(), true)
      |                                      ^
<source>:15:39: note: capture 'x' by value
   15 | constexpr auto h(auto x) -> decltype([]<bool = x.b>{}(), true)
      |                                       ^
      |                                       x
<source>:15:39: note: capture 'x' by reference
   15 | constexpr auto h(auto x) -> decltype([]<bool = x.b>{}(), true)
      |                                       ^
      |                                       &x
<source>:15:39: note: default capture by value
   15 | constexpr auto h(auto x) -> decltype([]<bool = x.b>{}(), true)
      |                                       ^
      |                                       =
<source>:15:39: note: default capture by reference
   15 | constexpr auto h(auto x) -> decltype([]<bool = x.b>{}(), true)
      |                                       ^
      |                                       &
```

The error message from MSVC with function `h`:

```
<source>(15): error C2065: 'x': undeclared identifier
<source>(17): error C2672: 'h': no matching overloaded function found
<source>(15): note: could be 'unknown-type h(_T0)'
<source>(17): note: Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type h(_T0)'
<source>(17): note: With the following template arguments:
<source>(17): note: '_T0=t'
<source>(15): note: call to object of class type '<lambda_2>': no matching
    call operator found
<source>(15): note: could be 'auto <lambda_2>::operator ()(void) const'
```

Comment: I'm fairly sure that each one of these is well-formed, and each compiler just runs into bugs in one case or the other. Note that GCC's output on trunk (https://godbolt.org/z/EMT3Khqrz) is nonsensical and spammy, so it has regressed even more than in the message you posted.

Comment: Using `t::b` works for all [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/K4f58hT5G).

Comment: Using `(x, t::b)` leads to same results as OP [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Eo1Grvn4v)

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks for pointing that out. It's also interesting to note that all compilers accept `auto a(t x) { return decltype(v<x.b>){}; }` while only GCC accepts `auto b(t x) -> decltype(v<x.b>);`. Whereas, when using the comma operator instead, only MSVC rejects `auto c(t x) { return decltype(v<(x, true)>){}; }` while only Clang accepts `auto d(t x) -> decltype(v<(x, true)>);`. When changing `t` to `auto` with the last two function declarations `c` and `d`, MSVC will also accept them.

Comment: I guess the question here is whether or not `x`, as a _local entity_, is _odr-usable_ where you try to use it, because you do _odr-use_ `x` in each example. I think `f` should be fine, but I am not sure about the rest. The rules for this have changed multiple times (as defect reports) since C++20 and C++20 also has some inconsistent use of relevant terminology ("declarative region") that was fixed by  P1787 for C++23.